# How to use node package dotenv to access local development environment variables in Red Hat OpenShift application?

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, openshift-online

I'm revisiting a project which hasn't been updated for a while.

In `production/online` environment, it uses environment variables defined at:

`openshift online console` > `applications` > `deployments` > `my node app` > `environment`

In `development/offline` environment, it uses environment variables defined at:

`./src/js/my_modules/local_settings` (this file is ignored by `.gitignore`)

The code looks something like:

```js
// check which environment we are in 
if (process.env.MONGODB_USER) {
    var online_status = "online";
}
else {
    var online_status = "offline";
}

// if online, use environment variables defined in red hat openshift  
if (online_status === 'online') {
    var site_title = process.env.SITE_TITLE;
    var site_description = process.env.SITE_DESCRIPTION;
    //etc 
}  

// if offline, get settings from a local file
else if (online_status === 'offline') {
    var local_settings = require('./src/js/my_modules/local_settings');
    var site_title = local_settings.SITE_TITLE;
    var site_description = local_settings.SITE_DESCRIPTION;
    // etc
}
```

I would like to install the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) in my local project repo via:

```
npm install dotenv
```

So that I can:

- Have my local settings in a `.env` file in the root of my project (ignored in `.gitignore`)
- Be able to use `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE` rather than `local_settings.SOME_VARIABLE`
- Get rid of some `if/else` blocks as both scenarios would point to `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE`

I'm a bit confused as to how this would effect the online environment.

Seeing as both `production/online` and `development/offline` environments would use:

```
var some_variable = process.env.SOME_VARIABLE_HERE
```

would the application automatically know to:

- Look at the local `.env` file when in development?
- Look at the Red Hat environment variables when in production?

And would adding the required instantiation at the beginning of the `server-side` file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

somehow make Red Hat OpenShift freak out (as it seems to already have its own 'things' in place to resolve references to `process.env.SOME_VARIABLE_HERE` to the relevant values defined in the OpenShift console)?

Comment: Can you create more environments in openshift or just dev and prod are available?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand meaning behind the question, I develop offline in local environment, and then push to github repo which updates online/production application.  I am not sure what 'creating more environments' means in this context, how it would resolve issue, and, if it is possible, how I would do it.  Apologies for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok. Some enterprises need an intermediate environment called testing or staging. In this environment another team validates and verifies what was done by the developer don't have bugs and complies the required features. This team is known as:  quality assurance, testers or qas

Answer (score 0):

To have a file by any environment (.dev .staging .prod) into the source code repository or manually in the server (it those are in .gitignore) worked for long time, **but now it goes against to the devops.**

The clean way is to use environment variables but managed remotely and obtained at the start of your application.

### How it works?

Basically your apps don't read or need a file (.env .properties, etc) with variables anymore. It loads them from a remote http service.

### Not intrusive

In this approach, you don't need specific languages variables (nodejs in your case). You just need to prepare your app to use environment variables. Your application don't care where the variables come from, just needs to be available at operative system level.

To achieve that, you just need to download the variables using a simple [shell code](https://github.com/jrichardsz-software-architect-tools/configurator/wiki/Linux-Client) or a very basic algorithm (http invocation) in your favorite language.

After that, after the start of your app, variables are ready to use at the most basic level.

```
var site_title = process.env.SITE_TITLE;
```

This approach is **not intrusive** because your app don't need something complex like library or algorithm in some programing language. Just needs the environment variables.

### Intrusive

Same as previous alternative but instead to read the variables direct from environment system, you should use or create a class/module in your language. This offer your the variables you need:

```
var site_title = VariablesManager.getProperty("SITE_TITLE");
```

**VariablesManager** at the startup must have consumed the variables from a remote service (http) and the store them to offer them to whoever needs it through **getProperty** method.

Also this **VariablesManager** usually has a feature called **hot-reload** which at intervals, update the variables consuming the remote variables manager. With this, if your application is running in production with real users and some variable needs to be updated, you just need to change it in the variables manager. Automatically your app will load the new values, **without restart or touching your app**

This approach is **intrusive** because you need to load advanced libraries in some programing language or create it.

### Devops

Your application just needs a few properties or settings  related to the consume of remote variables. For example: variables of **acme-web-staging**:

```
remote_variables_manager = https://variables.com/api
application_id = acme-web-staging
secure_key = *****
```

You could hide the secure key and parametrize the application_id using environment variables (created in the platform console)

```
remote_variables_manager = https://variables.com/api
application_id = ${application_id}
secure_key = ${remote_variables_manager_key}
```

Or if you want one variable manager by each environment

**staging**

```
remote_variables_manager = https://variables-staging.com/api
application_id = acme-web
secure_key = *****
```

**production**

```
remote_variables_manager = https://variables-staging.com/api
application_id = acme-web
secure_key = *****
```

### Variables manager

This concept was introduced many years ago. I used with java. It consist in a web application with features like:

- secure login
- create applications
- create variables of an application
- crypt sensitive values
- publish http endpoints to download or query the variables by application

Here a list of some ready to use alternatives:

- [Configurator](https://github.com/jrichardsz-software-architect-tools/configurator)

  - Nodejs & mysql solution. I developed this and I use it in various projects.
- [Doppler](https://www.doppler.com/)
- [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org)

  - http://www.therore.net/java/2015/05/03/distributed-configuration-with-zookeeper-curator-and-spring-cloud-config.html
- [Spring Cloud](http://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config#overview)

  - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration
  - This is a java spring framework functionality in which you can create properties file with configurations and configure your applications to read them.
- [Consul](https://www.consul.io/intro)

  - Consul is a service mesh solution providing a full featured control plane with service discovery, configuration, and segmentation functionality.
- doozerd, etcd

### In your specific case

- Don't use dot-env
- Use pure process.env.foo
- Deploy a remote variables manager in your openshift infraestructure
- Create just one variable in your openshift web console: APP_ENVIRONMENT
- In your code at the start, do something like this:

```
if (process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT === "PROD")
  //get variables from remote service using 
  //some http client like axios, request, etc
  //then inject them to your process.env
  process.env.site_url = remoteVariables.site_url
else
  //we are in local developer workspace
  //so, nothing complex is required
  //developer should inject manually 
  //before the startup: npm run start or dev
  //export site_url = "acme.com"
```

If you can configure an execution of a shell script before the start of your openshift app, you could load and expose the variables at that stage and the previous snippet would not be necessary because the variables will be ready to be retrieved using **process.env** directly in your app